# The current request for action 'Create' on controller type 'WeeklyTargetController' is ambiguous between the following action methods:

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I've seen this problem a lot here but my issue is slightly different. I already have two Create actions that had been generated by MVC out of the box, listed as so (one's GET, one's POST):

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
//stuff...
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include="WeeklyTargetId,UserId,WeekId,Hours")] WeeklyTarget weeklytarget)
{
//stuff...
}
```

My issue is that I'm trying to update the Create View based on a DropDown that I've added onto the page wrapped inside it's own form, where on submission the user can filter another dropdown on the main Create form. Here is my seperate wrapped form on the Create view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
<p>        
    <span>
        Filter By Practice:
        @Html.DropDownList("Practice", (List<SelectListItem>) ViewBag.PracticeList, new { @onchange = "this.form.submit();"})
    </span>

</p>
}
```

My reasoning is that when the user selects a practice to filter by, the onchange event will submit the form and kick this new Create Action I've wrote off:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Create(FormCollection formCollection)
{
//do the filtering stuff...
}
```

However, as I've come to realize MVC doesn't look at method signatures to override ambiguity and there can only be two Create actions. What are my options? Am I going about this completely wrong? Is there a way I can have the filter form submission route to a different action name instead of Create? Keep in mind this is all on the Create View and I'll be returning to this afterwards. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create the form via the `BeginForm` method you can specify the action and controller.

```
Html.BeginForm("FilterAction", "ControllerName")
```

Then inside the action, you could filter your model on whatever it is that is in your SelectList via the ViewBag.

More information can be found here:

[FormExtensions.BeginForm Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)